# Can I use a dumb component as my top-level component with React/Redux App?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, components

I have the following setup:

#### index.js

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Route component={App} />
        <Route component={Layout} >
            <Route path="/about-us" component={About} />
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Route>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  target
);
```

#### app.js

```
class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

## layout.js

```
class Layout extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And then I would have connected components for `Home` and `About`. I figured that because those connected components are used with a `Route`, they would have access to the `store` at the high level. And then those connected components then are treated as the top connected component. Is there any issue with doing this?

Comment: I don't see any issue but also don't understand the purpose of it

Comment: Can you update the question with more information about the reasoning behind the nesting of routes? Because to my knowledge, after react router v4 there hasn't been a need for Route nesting.

Answer (score 2):

To use Redux, put the components in a provider

```
<Provider store={store}>
    [Components]  
</Provider>
```

and map your actions and redux state to your component's props. Components just need to be a child of the Provider of the store.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';    


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    ...props: ...state.reducer.desired_props
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        ...props: ...action_creator  // () => { type: '', payload: {} }
    }, dispatch)
}


const funcComp = (props) => {
    return (<div>{props.message}</div>)
}
const reduxReady = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(funcComp)


// or


class classyComp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div>{this.props.message}</div>)
    }
}
const alsoReduxReady = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(classyComp)
```

Could be anywhere

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Anything>
        <reduxReady />
        <alsoReduxReady />
    </Anything>
</Provider>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, no problem.

The store is spread through the component hierarchy via react context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).
So a component will give the reference to the redux store to all it's children, even when it's not itself connected.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely have dumb components wrapping smart components, just to define a layout for their children. Often, the best approach is having the leaves of the virtual DOM tree connecting to the store, that way it makes easier to check for changes of the state and only trigger a `render` when really necessary.

Here's a wonderful post about this topic, from the co-author of the Redux, Dan Abramov: [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)